# Ratios and Percents Population Word Problem

Tags: word-problem, ratio

If in 9 years Town A's population rose 12% and Town B's population rose 22%, and if together the populations of Town's A and B rise by 16%. Then what was the ratio  of Town A's population to Town B's population 9 years ago?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the populations of both towns nine years ago be $A,B$ respectively.

Hence, after nine years the population of the towns becomes,
$$A' = 1.12A$$
$$B' = 1.22B$$
and,
$$A'+ B' = 1.16(A+B)$$
$$\therefore 1.12A + 1.22B = 1.16(A+B)$$
$$\therefore 0.04A = 0.06B$$
$$\therefore 2A = 3B$$
$$\therefore \frac{A}{B} = \frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Letting $a$ and $b$ be the initial populations of towns A and B respectively, the given information says:

$1.12a+1.22b=1.16(a+b)$

Now see what you can find out by separating the $a$ and $b$ terms in the equation.